# JEST Client is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have been stuck with this from a couple of days, any help will be highly appreciable.

How actually we retrieve the documents from the result object of Jest client

I am using the following below code

```
List<Hit<Part,Void>> hits =  searchresult.getHits(Part.class);
            for (SearchResult.Hit<Part,Void> hit : hits) {
```

Here in Part PPOJO class I have a variable  attributes

```
private Object attributes;
```

Here is the mapping of the attributes field, it is of object type.

```
 "attributes": {
                  "properties": {
                     "AttrCatgId": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "AttrCatgText": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "AttrText": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "AttributeId": {
                        "type": "long"
                     }
                  }
               }
```

Now when I'm retrieving the documents from the result object, it's giving me the values in double format ( .0 is appending by default)

```
{AttrText=3/4 TON, AttrCatgText=LOAD RATING, AttrCatgId=3.0, AttributeId=11.0}
```

How to get the  AttrText=3/4 TON, AttrCatgText=LOAD RATING, AttrCatgId=3, AttributeId=11 Values in this format.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is the sample Document.

```
       "catalogLineCode": "G12",
       "supplierId": [
          5904
       ],
       "partId": 5278493,
       "partGrpName": "Thermostat, Gasket & Housing",
       "terminologyName": "Rear Right Wheel Cylinder",
       "catalogName": "EPE",
       "catId": [
          10
       ],
       "perCarQty": 1,
       "catalogId": 1,
       "partGrpId": 10,
       "regionId": 1,
       "partNumber": "12T1B",
       "attributes": [
          {
             "AttrText": "3/4 TON",
             "AttrCatgText": "LOAD RATING",
             "AttrCatgId": 3,
             "AttributeId": 11
          },
          {
             "AttrText": "M ENG CODE",
             "AttrCatgText": "ENG SOURCE CODE",
             "AttrCatgId": 16,
             "AttributeId": 111
          },
          {
             "AttrText": "4 WHEEL/ALL WHEEL DRIVE",
             "AttrCatgText": "DRIVE TYPE",
             "AttrCatgId": 27,
             "AttributeId": 168
          }
       ],
       "vehicleId": [
          5274
       ],
       "extendedDescription": "ALTERNATE TEMP - ALL MAKES-STD LINE~STD CAB - BASE",
       "terminologyId": 20
```

Comment: @val wishing to get your remarks on this .!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I need to see the real mapping in your index. Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/part` ?

Comment: Hi val,I have updated the sample document in my question.